# Matching everything but words, numbers and spaces

Tags: regex, python-3.x

This code will replace everything except for words, but how do I get it to also leave the numbers and spaces untouched? e.g. "I didn't see him until 1." -> "I didnt see him until 1"

```
text = regex.sub("\P{alpha}+","",text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use Python’s `re` library on Unicode. It works very poorly.  Use [Matthew Barnett’s `regex` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) instead.  It works much, much better.

It also runs on both Python 2 and 3 and on both narrow and wide builds, but for reasons largely unrelated to that particular library I strongly recommend that you run only a wide build of Python 3 and eschew all other combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Python regexes don't support Unicode properties. You can try:

```
text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+","",text)
```

Instead. If you do have something like [Ponyguruma](http://sandbox.pocoo.org/) installed, you can use:

```
text = re.sub("[\P{Alnum}\PZ]+","",text) # pZ is shorthand for p{Separator}
```